# Is this ListView bug?

Tags: win32gui

if create WC_LISTVIEW with LVS_REPORT style and set both LVSIL_SMALL and LVSIL_STATE (or with LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES) image lists and heigth of small images is less than heigth of state images - list incorrectly displayed: small images not centered by Y, but on same line with state images, and bottom lines (exactly CY_state - CY_small) is filled by trash. for example on high DPI display, ListView with LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES use 20 pixel heigth for CY_state, if use 15 pixel small icons - will be ~next picture (left side of image). if change state images heigh to <= CY_small will be normal displayed (right side of image)
this is known bug ? or exist ways resolve this ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

yes, this is ListView bug - present in all windows versions, including latest win10 builds.

bug in function

> int CLVView::ComputeCYItemSize()

here exist next code:

```
int CLVView::ComputeCYItemSize() // this -> CLVReportView
{
    // CListView* _pListView;
    CLVImageListManager* p = _pListView->_pImageListManager;
    ...
    if (p->_himlState)
    {
        p->_cySmall = max(p->_cyState, p->_cySmall);// bug !! need remove this line
    ...
    }
  ...
}
```

if 'nop'

> p->_cySmall = max(p->_cyState, p->_cySmall)

under debugger - all begin working ok and have next view:

[image]